# The Sports Riddle

Tags: mathematics, rhyme, knowledge, sports

--The Sports Riddle--

> Rounded up, the acceleration of free fall is exactly _______
>
> Multiply it by Pi, don't forget to  round it down, otherwise the answer will never ______
>
> Take away 8, you'll get a man many like to call goat
>
> Although another man with this number is considered to be in the same boat
>
> The first's name is _______ and the latter's name is _________
>
> As soon as the first one exited, the other one came
>
> Now hold on, I'm sure you've figured it out, don't be in a hurry
>
> Because if we took away 1 instead of 8, we'd be talking about ________  ___________

Comment: Eh, does this require extensive knowledge of some particular sport? And is it a universally played sport? Or is it played only in some specific countries?

Comment: Not extensive really :). For the most part, someone can figure out the answers as these people are well known.

Comment: Also see the above(albeit a bit late) edit in the comment and give your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounded up, the acceleration of free fall is exactly _______

> Ten

Multiply it by Pi, don't forget to round it down, otherwise the answer will never ______

> End

Take away 8, you'll get a man many call like to call goat

Although another man with this number is considered to be in the same boat

The first's name is _______ and the latter's name is _________

> (Micheal) Jordan, (LeBron) James; both of whom wore #23

As soon as the first one exited, the other one came

Now hold on, I'm sure you've figured it out, don't be in a hurry

Because if we took away 1 instead of 8, we'd be talking about ________ ___________

> Steph Curry

Comment: How do you get Jordan and James from the question?

Comment: @Sid they wear shirt no. 23

Comment: GOAT = Greatest of all time

Comment: @BrownEyedNinja any reason why you left out the word 'end'?

Comment: @BrownEyedNinja personally I'm not 100% sure this is a puzzle, and people in chat seem to agree. I only usually upvote high quality puzzles, and no offense, and this is understandable and common as this is your first puzzle, but I'm afraid I don't think it is high quality... don't give up though! Take a look at some other puzzles, and see if you can make some better ones! :)